# Why do I get this error when using Expanded

Tags: flutter

After many attempts and trying different things, I get the same error ( throw constraintsError  ) as soon as I add Expanded, while the error disappears by deleting it,, i I want the upper part to be fixed and the other part to be Scrollable

thanks

```js
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
         children: [ 
           Column(
            children: [
               Container(), // fixed
               Row(), // fixed
               **Expanded**(
                 child: Container(
                    color: constants.kLightGrayColor,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    controller: controller.scrollController,
                    itemCount: data.posts.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

[image]

Comment: you can remove top level scrollable widget while the only Listview needed to be scrollable .

Comment: Please remove the `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: I did this but scrolling stopped at  listview, and received this error message (A RenderFlex overflowed by 1936 pixels on the bottom.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly cannot used `Expanded` inside `SingleChildScrollView`.
to work normally pls remove `SingleChildScrollView` widget and remove outer `Column`,
used one of `Column` in green box.
[image]
*it is small example*

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 200,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: const Center(child: Text("Fixed Box")),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 20,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("$index"),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]